# Detect if RTP stream is EVS or OPUS?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, opus

Is there any way to detect if a rtp stream is using EVS or OPUS codec? I have an issue with a voip server reporting wrong sdp information in sip signalization. I need to workaround this issue.. I want to inspect the packets for these two codecs (EVS and OPUS) and correct sip sdp signalization. Any ideas for codec detection if I have a rtp packet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the PT Field of the RTP header:

```
payload type (PT) : 7 bits
```

This field identifies the format of the RTP payload and determines its interpretation by the application.

Comment: Payload identifiers 96–127 are used for payloads defined dynamically so it doesn't help in my case.